# Inconsistently getting NumberFormatException when trying to convert binary to hex

Tags: java, binary, hex, data-conversion, number-systems

If use variable bin1 it wont convert, however if i replace the parameter with bin2 it seems to work.

I tried using long instead of int. It's still the same.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bin1 = "11011100000000010001000000000000";
        String bin2 = "01100100001000010001000000000000";

        int dec = Integer.parseInt(bin1, 2);
        String hex = Integer.toString(dec, 16);

        System.out.println(hex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works fine with longs.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bin1 = "11011100000000010001000000000000";
        String bin2 = "01100100001000010001000000000000";

        long dec = Long.parseLong(bin1, 2);
        String hex = Long.toString(dec, 16);

        System.out.println(hex);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
dc011000
```

Your number is simply too big for an `int`.

Comment: thanks. do i delete this post now? I tried it, long but not how you implemented. i missed that one.

Comment: @BWB You don't need to delete it. This site is for questions and answers that might be useful to other visitors in future.